# SQL Server data caching in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, caching

I am trying to use caching to save time refreshing my web application and do so automatically whenever the database changes, and am having trouble setting up the cache.

I have added the following code to where I access SQL...

```
SqlDependency.Start("Data Source=" + serverName + ";" + 
                    "Initial Catalog=...;" + "User Id=...;Password=...;");
```

and then after the SQL connection is made and just before I pull data from SQL...

```
SqlCacheDependency dependency = new SqlCacheDependency(command);

int numberOfMinutes = 3;
DateTime expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(numberOfMinutes);

Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(expires);
Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
Current.Response.AddCacheDependency(dependency);
```

Previously in the method that this code is in, I accessed SQL and returned a list of objects from SQL. What further steps do I need to do to set up the cache? I'm assuming I have to add the data to the cache somehow and then retrieve it from the cache somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `HttpRuntime.Cache` cache object

I would write a generic method to `GET` and `SET` cache object.

```
 public T GetOrSetCache<T>
    (string key,T obj, int cacheTime) where T:class,new()
{
    System.Web.Caching.Cache cacheContainer = HttpRuntime.Cache;
    T cacheObj = cacheContainer.Get(key) as T;

    if (cacheObj == null)
    {
        cacheContainer.Insert(key,
            obj,
            null, 
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(cacheTime),
            System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        cacheObj = obj;
    }

    return cacheObj;
}
```

When you want to use cache you can do like this on your main code

```
var data = [read data from data base]
int numberOfMinutes = 3;
data = GetOrSetCache("name1",data,numberOfMinutes );
```

[HttpRuntime.Cache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache(v=vs.110).aspx)

**NOTE**

1. `Cache` is a key/value` collection
2. Get instance from `cache` you need to provide a key.
3. Set instance into `cache` you need to provide a key and instance object.

Comment: Will this cache get automatically updated if I use it like you have described and my SQL table gets updated at some point?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is impossible,because cache main intention is keep something in memory if you want to use the data you can get it immediately,that don't have to request db,but your comment request not the same as the main intention of the cache

Comment: if your data often update and need data consistency, i will recommend you don't use cache.